# possible loss of precision error when using Math.floor() in java

Tags: java

when i try to compile this program it shows the following error :

src (master)$ javac AmstrongNumber.java

AmstrongNumber.java:26: error: possible loss of precision
          length = Math.floor(Math.log10(input)) + 1;
                                                 ^
  required: int

found:    double
1 error

can any one clarify what is loss of precision error in java ?
but doesn't Math.floor() return a int value. when i use (int) type casting instead of Math.floor() it 
shows no errors 
thank you in advance.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class AmstrongNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      double input;
      int length;
      double copy;
      double output = 0.0;
      double modulus;


      Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print(" Enter a number : ");
      input = stdin.nextInt();


      // find number of digits in the input
      length = Math.floor(Math.log10(input)) + 1;
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println(" no. of digits in the number is : " + length);
      System.out.println();
      copy = input;

      for(int n = 0; n < length; n++ ) {
        modulus = copy % 10; // find the last digit of the number
        copy = (int) copy / 10; // discarding the last digit
        output = output + Math.pow(modulus, (double)length);
      }

      if((int)input == (int)output) 
         System.out.printf(" %d is a Amstrong number ", (int)input);
      else 
         System.out.printf(" %d is not a Amstrong number ", (int)input);

  }
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Possible loss of precision" in my Java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603223/possible-loss-of-precision-in-my-java-program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but doesn't Math.floor() return a int value

No. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double))

> static double floor(double a) Returns the largest (closest to positive
>   infinity) double value that is less than or equal to the argument and
>   is equal to a mathematical integer.

Yes, casting to an int is safe here, and will give you the result you want.

Comment: And if you are wondering *why* floor still returns a double instead of just an int, this is also in the JavaDoc: "If the argument is NaN or an infinity or positive zero or negative zero, then the result is the same as the argument." This is something an int can't do, int doesn't have infinity, NaN etc.