# Java program to check if number is happy yields an impossible output

Tags: java, numbers, runtime-error

I've designed a program to input a number and check whether it is happy.

```
import java.util.*;

public class isHappy
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    int l = String.valueOf(n).length();
    int temp=n;

    int midVar=0, addVar=0, i=0;

    while (temp!=4)
    {
        midVar=0;

        for (i=l; i>0; i--)
        {
            addVar = temp/Math.pow(10, i);
            midVar+=Math.sqrt(addVar);
        }

        temp = midVar;

        if (temp==1)
          break;
    }

    if (temp==1)
    {
        System.out.println("Happy number");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Unhappy number");
    }
}
}
```

I do admit that the code I've used is not entirely clean, but it should work. And it certainly should not yield the output 2. Yes, that's it: After the user enters the number, the program just displays 2 in the next line. Let me walk you through the execution process.

```
Enter number:                                       //program output
68                                                  //user input
2                                                   //program output
```

I must add that I do in fact get a 'possible loss of precision' error during compilation, but I don't believe it actually might be a factor in the inexplicable output. Also, my main purpose in asking this question is not to get answers as to how to repair my code, but an explanation as to why I get the aforementioned strange output.

Comment: i think you may get compile time error? `temp/Math.pow(10, i)`.

Comment: post your real code .

Comment: I do get a "Possible loss of precision" warning, but I don't think that should be a problem. Wouldn't Java automatically round that off to the nearest integer? Or is that the cause of my problem?

Comment: Fast Snail This is my real code.

Comment: `Possible loss of precision error` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603223/possible-loss-of-precision-in-my-java-program

Comment: Can't reproduce the example you have given.

Comment: @user3460322 if this is real code then you should get a compile error \

Comment: Are you sure that's the whole code? 1. As Satya wrote - it won't compile. 2. I don't see any line that can print to to screen the value `2`. Are you mixing in between two projects you're working on?

Comment: Yes, I did get a 'possible loss of precision' error, but I discarded it at the time as an unimportant warning and just executed the code. Now I see I definitely should not have done that.

Comment: @TDG Exactly. There is absolutely no reason why 2 would be printed, even if my code is wrong, and that bothers me. I'm going to modify the code to combat the precision loss error, but I don't really think that has anything to do with the inexplicable output.

Answer (score 0):

**Happy Numbers according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number) is:**

A `happy number` is a number defined by the following process:

Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number either equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1.

Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy numbers, while those that do not end in 1 are unhappy numbers (or sad numbers).

Example:

For example, 19 is happy, as the associated sequence is:

1^2 + 9^2 = 82

8^2 + 2^2 = 68

6^2 + 8^2 = 100

1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1.

Code: Some modifications to get Happy Numbers.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    int l = String.valueOf(n).length();
    int temp = n;

    int midVar = 0, addVar = 0, i = 0;

    while (temp != 4) {
        midVar = 0;

        while (temp != 0) {
            addVar = temp % 10;
            temp = temp / 10;
            midVar += Math.pow(addVar, 2);
        }
        temp = midVar;
        System.out.println(midVar);


        if (temp == 1) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (temp == 1) {
        System.out.println("Happy number");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unhappy number");
    }
}
```

Comment: Rohit, your solution is absolutely correct, but I'm not aiming solely at the solution of my problem. I'm actually more concerned about why I get the impossible output 2.

Comment: well, when i copied your code. There is 1 compilation error i.e casting to int .
Here:  addVar = temp/Math.pow(10, i); - it should be  addVar = (int) temp/Math.pow(10, i); 

Considering your output - I guess its the temp value - 2 (i am not sure).
I am concern about what IDE you are using because the code has compilation errors and even if you run you should get runtimeexception.

Comment: I've had some issues with Eclipse lately, so while I redownloaded it, I decided to see just why Coding Ground is so popular. This program was executed in the Coding Ground IDE.

Comment: well, I was not able to run it on Coding Ground, but see here at ideone.com -  https://ideone.com/wu4wWi. It is giving compilation info - 

Main.java:28: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
            addVar = temp/Math.pow(10, i);